# Create Dynamic AND clause in mysql query using PHP

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I am writing SQL Query based on array values but I am getting the wrong result.

For Example if my array values are **['PAK','USA']** then Query should be:-

```
Select * From `search` WHERE country = 'PAK' AND country = 'USA'
```

and if array values are **['USA','China']** then Query should be:-

```
Select * From `search` WHERE country = 'USA' AND country = 'China'
```

and so on..

I am doing this but I am getting the wrong result like this:-

```
SELECT * FROM `search` WHERE country = '' AND country = 'Pakistan' AND country = 'United States'
```

I am wondering why **country = ''** is always adding at the beginning of Query.. This is why I am getting the wrong result. Please help me out. Thanks in advance.. Below is my code..

**PHP**

```
$query_parts = array();

foreach($_POST['countryArray'] as $array){          
    $query_parts[] = "'".$array."'";
}
$string = implode(' AND country = ', $query_parts);
//echo $string;

$query =  "SELECT * FROM `search` WHERE country = {$string}";

echo $query;
```

Comment: Use `!empty($array)`  inside foreach loop to avoid blank value!!

Comment: can you please post the $_POST['countryArray'] here.it works fine if the array is like $test = array("USA","China");

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code is fine.

But, blank elements from array are not restricted.

The array `$_POST['countryArray']` has a blank element.

You can filter it with [array_filter()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php):

```
$_POST['countryArray'] = array_filter($_POST['countryArray']);
```

Final Code:

```
$query_parts = array();
$_POST['countryArray'] = array_filter($_POST['countryArray']);
foreach($_POST['countryArray'] as $array){
  $query_parts[] = "'".$array."'";
}
$string = implode(' AND country = ', $query_parts);
//echo $string;
$query =  "SELECT * FROM `search` WHERE country = {$string}";
echo $query;
```

Comment: 1 more question how if I want to include another different AND For this. For Example. Select * From ``search`` WHERE country = 'PAK' AND country = 'USA' AND product_name like ="%$myvariable%".. How I add product_name like in this code.. Thanks in advance...

Comment: @Junaidafzal if this answer works for you, please mark this as an answer because it might help other users in future.

Comment: @Junaidafzal, simply follow the steps for country and concat the query.